# Java JButton clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
    int buttonNum = size[0] * size[1];
    panelForButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(size[0], size[1]));

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[buttonNum];
    buttonsArray = buttons;

    for (int i = 0; i < buttonNum; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
       //           Change each button size
       buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        panelForButtons.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].setBackground(Color.black);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(new Actions());
    }
    panelOnTheLeft.add(panelForButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);
}

static class Actions implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {0
    }
```

I want every button generated from the for loop to get the function of changing the background colour when the button is clicked. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the background color of each button to be changed when it gets clicked:

I would probably not make the Actions class static.

In `actionPerformed()`, get the button that was clicked from `e`, set its background color.

In the for loop, don't make a `new Actions()` every time it loops. Make ONE instance before the loop starts, and pass it in during the loop.

```java
int buttonNum = size[0] * size[1];
panelForButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(size[0], size[1]));

JButton[] buttons = new JButton[buttonNum];
buttonsArray = buttons;

// The only action handler you need
Actions myActionHandler = new Actions();

for (int i = 0; i < buttonNum; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();

    // Change each button size
    buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    buttons[i].setBackground(Color.black);
    
    // Just pass in the one we already have from above
    buttons[i].addActionListener(myActionHandler);

    panelForButtons.add(buttons[i]);
}

panelOnTheLeft.add(panelForButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);


class Actions implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Get the button that was clicked
        JButton theButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
        // Set it's background color to white
        theButton.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
```